# Making a Python Project work on another Mac

Tags: python

I have a python project with a bunch of modules and directories.

It runs as a CLI, and now I want another user able to run it on their system.

I exported my conda environment using:

```
conda env export  --file environment.yml
```

It looks something like this:

```
name: ds
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _pytorch_select=0.1=cpu_0
  - appnope=0.1.0=py37hc8dfbb8_1001
  - attrs=19.3.0=py_0
  - backcall=0.1.0=py_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - bleach=3.1.4=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h0b31af3_2
  - ca-certificates=2020.6.20=hecda079_0
  - cairo=1.16.0=hec6a9b0_1003
  - certifi=2020.6.20=py37hc8dfbb8_0
  - cffi=1.14.0=py37h356ff06_0
  - chardet=3.0.4=py37hc8dfbb8_1006
  - click=7.1.2=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - curl=7.69.1=h2d98d24_0
  - cycler=0.10.0=py_2
  - dbus=1.13.6=h2f22bb5_0
  - decorator=4.4.2=py_0
  - defusedxml=0.6.0=py_0
  - entrypoints=0.3=py37hc8dfbb8_1001
  - et_xmlfile=1.0.1=py_1001
  - expat=2.2.9=h4a8c4bd_2
  - ffmpeg=4.2=h5c2b479_0
  - fontconfig=2.13.1=h6b1039f_1001
  - freetype=2.10.1=h8da9a1a_0
  - gettext=0.19.8.1=h46ab8bc_1002
  - ghostscript=9.22=h0a44026_1001
  - giflib=5.2.1=h0b31af3_2
  - glib=2.64.2=h577aef8_0
  - gmp=6.2.0=h4a8c4bd_2
  - gnutls=3.6.5=h53004b3_1002
  - graphite2=1.3.13=h12caacf_1001
  - harfbuzz=2.4.0=hd8d2a14_3
  - hdf5=1.10.6=nompi_h3e39495_100
  - icu=64.2=h6de7cb9_1
  - importlib-metadata=1.6.0=py37hc8dfbb8_0
  - importlib_metadata=1.6.0=0
  - ipykernel=5.2.1=py37h43977f1_0
  - ipython=7.13.0=py37hc8dfbb8_2
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py_1
  - ipywidgets=7.5.1=py_0
  - jasper=1.900.1=h636a363_1006
  - jdcal=1.4.1=py_0
  - jedi=0.17.0=py37hc8dfbb8_0
  - jinja2=2.11.2=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - joblib=0.14.1=py_0
  - jpeg=9c=h1de35cc_1001
  - jsonschema=3.2.0=py37hc8dfbb8_1
  - jupyter=1.0.0=py_2
  - jupyter_client=6.1.3=py_0
  - jupyter_console=6.1.0=py_1
  - jupyter_core=4.6.3=py37hc8dfbb8_1
  - kiwisolver=1.2.0=py37ha1cc60f_0
  - krb5=1.17.1=h1752a42_0
  - lame=3.100=h1de35cc_1001
  - libblas=3.8.0=14_mkl
  - libcblas=3.8.0=14_mkl
  - libclang=9.0.1=default_hf57f61e_0
  - libcurl=7.69.1=hc0b9707_0
  - libcxx=9.0.1=1
  - libedit=3.1.20170329=hcfe32e1_1001
  - libffi=3.2.1=h4a8c4bd_1007
  - libgfortran=4.0.0=2
  - libiconv=1.15=h0b31af3_1006
  - liblapack=3.8.0=14_mkl
  - liblapacke=3.8.0=14_mkl
  - libllvm9=9.0.1=h7475705_1
  - libopencv=4.2.0=py37_6
  - libpng=1.6.37=hbbe82c9_1
  - libpq=12.2=h489d428_1
  - libsodium=1.0.17=h01d97ff_0
  - libssh2=1.8.2=hcdc9a53_2
  - libtiff=4.1.0=ha78913b_3
  - libwebp=1.0.2=hd3bf737_5
  - libxml2=2.9.10=h53d96d6_0
  - libxslt=1.1.33=h320ff13_0
  - llvm-openmp=10.0.0=h28b9765_0
  - lxml=4.5.1=py37heb1707f_0
  - lz4-c=1.9.2=h4a8c4bd_0
  - markupsafe=1.1.1=py37h9bfed18_1
  - matplotlib-base=3.2.1=py37hddda452_0
  - mistune=0.8.4=py37h9bfed18_1001
  - mkl=2019.5=281
  - mkl-service=2.3.0=py37h0b31af3_0
  - nbconvert=5.6.1=py37hc8dfbb8_1
  - nbformat=5.0.6=py_0
  - ncurses=6.1=h0a44026_1002
  - nettle=3.4.1=h3efe00b_1002
  - ninja=1.10.0=ha1b3eb9_0
  - notebook=6.0.3=py37_0
  - nspr=4.20=h0a44026_1000
  - nss=3.47=hc0980d9_0
  - numpy=1.18.1=py37h7687784_1
  - opencv=4.2.0=py37_6
  - openh264=1.8.0=hd9629dc_1000
  - openjpeg=2.3.1=h254dc36_3
  - openpyxl=3.0.3=py_0
  - openssl=1.1.1g=h0b31af3_0
  - pandas=1.0.3=py37h94625e5_1
  - pandoc=2.9.2.1=0
  - pandocfilters=1.4.2=py_1
  - parso=0.7.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - patsy=0.5.1=py_0
  - pcre=8.44=h4a8c4bd_0
  - pdfminer.six=20191020=py_2
  - pexpect=4.8.0=py37hc8dfbb8_1
  - pickleshare=0.7.5=py37hc8dfbb8_1001
  - pip=20.0.2=py_2
  - pixman=0.38.0=h01d97ff_1003
  - poppler=0.87.0=h3232a60_1
  - poppler-data=0.4.9=1
  - prometheus_client=0.7.1=py_0
  - prompt-toolkit=3.0.5=py_0
  - prompt_toolkit=3.0.5=0
  - ptyprocess=0.6.0=py_1001
  - py-opencv=4.2.0=py37h43977f1_6
  - pycparser=2.20=py_0
  - pycryptodome=3.9.7=py37h51495b9_1
  - pygments=2.6.1=py_0
  - pyparsing=2.4.7=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - pypdf2=1.26.0=py_2
  - pyqt=5.12.3=py37he22c54c_1
  - pyrsistent=0.16.0=py37h9bfed18_0
  - python=3.7.6=h90870a6_5_cpython
  - python-dateutil=2.8.1=py_0
  - python_abi=3.7=1_cp37m
  - pytorch=1.4.0=cpu_py37hf9bb1df_0
  - pytz=2019.3=py_0
  - pyyaml=5.3.1=py37h9bfed18_0
  - pyzmq=19.0.0=py37haec44b1_1
  - qt=5.12.5=h514805e_3
  - qtconsole=4.7.3=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - qtpy=1.9.0=py_0
  - readline=8.0=hcfe32e1_0
  - scikit-learn=0.22.2.post1=py37h3dc85bc_0
  - scipy=1.4.1=py37hce1b9e5_3
  - seaborn=0.10.1=py_0
  - send2trash=1.5.0=py_0
  - setuptools=46.1.3=py37hc8dfbb8_0
  - six=1.14.0=py_1
  - sortedcontainers=2.1.0=py_0
  - sqlite=3.30.1=h93121df_0
  - statsmodels=0.11.1=py37h9bfed18_1
  - terminado=0.8.3=py37hc8dfbb8_1
  - testpath=0.4.4=py_0
  - tk=8.6.10=hbbe82c9_0
  - tornado=6.0.4=py37h9bfed18_1
  - traitlets=4.3.3=py37hc8dfbb8_1
  - wcwidth=0.1.9=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - webencodings=0.5.1=py_1
  - wheel=0.34.2=py_1
  - widgetsnbextension=3.5.1=py37_0
  - x264=1!152.20180806=h1de35cc_0
  - xlrd=1.2.0=py_0
  - xz=5.2.5=h0b31af3_0
  - yaml=0.2.4=h0b31af3_0
  - zeromq=4.3.2=h6de7cb9_2
  - zipp=3.1.0=py_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=h0b31af3_1006
  - zstd=1.4.4=h4b3e974_3
  - pip:
    - distro==1.5.0
    - pdftotext==2.1.4
    - pyqt5-sip==4.19.18
    - pyqtwebengine==5.12.1
    - tabula-py==2.1.0
prefix: /anaconda3/envs/ds
```

Now my question is can I ask the new user just take this environment.yml file and run:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

in their Terminal and would it also install the Python version (3.7.6) along with anaconda or they would first have to install the Python 3.7.6 separately and Anaconda and then run the above environment.yml file?

Also, would the mac os version impact the functioning of the above packages on the different system?

I know a docker takes care of os version everything, but can't use docker and my project requires the user to enter few command line arguments and pass their data directory so it can't be just a file they click and everything runs. There is a need from them to enter the arguments

That is why felt asking them to install the environment might replicate the same env and the python script can run in their system

Comment: BTW a little off-topic: "my project requires the user to enter few command line arguments"... in a Dockerfile you can set your program as the ``ENTRYPOINT`` and then you would be able to pass parameters using ``docker run``. Just so you know for another situation where Docker might be suitable for you.

Comment: i knw docker can do tht. Thats why mentioned it. But I can't use docker internally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install some Conda, you can use [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) to get the bare minimum essentials. The Python interpreter needed is defined in your YAML file and will be installed as required. Miniconda already includes a barebones Python interpreter for its own functionality.

Comment: Thanks. So install miniconda and then ask the user to run the above conda create environment in their terminal. Do u think a different mac os might interfer same working as on my system?

Comment: Unless you're not using some specific macOS APIs that might change within versions, it shouldn't be a problem. But you gotta test it to be sure.

Comment: ok. I just saw that miniconda on anaconda website is available for python 3.8 on mac os. I am using 3.7.6 in my environment. Will that be ok>

Comment: when the environment is created, Python 3.7 will be downloaded for the environment

Comment: ok.. just to confirm- miniconda package is for 3.8. but the python it will use is 3.7.6 as mentioned in the environment by downloading 3.7.6. Does it mean I wud hv two python version?

Comment: conda will install python 3.8, but when you _activate_ the environment [managing environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) it will use python 3.7 for that session

Comment: so it will hv two python version installed in the system. Main 3.8 and 3.7 in a particular env

Comment: Yes. If you have more questions after this comment, please move the discussion to a chat